# How to apply a pre-designed function in dplyr with group_by function

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a pre-designed function like below, which I checked and work well.

```
foo <- function(tmp2) {
  
tmp2[,"frontier_dummy"] <- 0
A=tmp2[1,"sd_R"] # minimum sd
tmp2[1,"frontier_dummy"] <- 1

for (i in 2:nrow(tmp2)) {
  
  # check whether sd_i < A
  if(tmp2[i,"sd_R"]<A){
    tmp2[i,"frontier_dummy"] <- 1
    A <- tmp2[i, "sd_R"]
  }
}
return(tmp2)
}
```

I would like to apply this function to dplyr together with a group_by function. I have my code like below:

```
trial2= tmp2%>% group_by(subset) %>% arrange(desc(mean_R),desc(sd_R)) %>%
  foo()
```

it works but when I checked the output, it does not work as separate the data into subsets then run the function for each subset. Can anyone help my figure out why? How can I modify my code?

Thanks a lot!!!!!!

the data:

,id,mean_R,Var_R,sd_R,mean_over_sd,mean_ROI,subset
1,11813,3385.833333,3868920.967,1966.957286,1.7213558,55832.47936,3
2,4049,2150.625,4000830.839,2000.207699,1.075200841,67073.8136,6
3,11432,1959.4,2508571.822,1583.847159,1.23711432,69286.36564,4
4,15166,1600.357143,13464947.17,3669.461428,0.436128618,280618.3547,3
5,12061,1509.5,44193,210.221312,7.180527921,25810.03176,3
6,7749,1452.4,297037.3,545.0112843,2.664898951,71970.11657,2
7,10711,1433.461538,14059975.44,3749.663376,0.382290727,131054.4251,2
8,3068,1252.25,333918.25,577.8565999,2.167060133,42896.49156,4
9,11335,1111.125,133857.8393,365.8658761,3.036973581,61310.80272,2
10,5770,692.8,196306.1778,443.06453,1.563654847,59234.55409,2
11,10089,679.375,56943.58333,238.6285468,2.846998019,60651.76025,1
12,10674,674.6666667,241327.8667,491.2513274,1.373363549,24164.31565,2
13,11435,531.8333333,669476.5667,818.2154769,0.649991779,11331.40683,2
14,19957,518.16,314590.14,560.8833569,0.923828446,70713.39092,1
15,22841,430.2,114384.0833,338.2071604,1.272001455,49212.42332,2
16,10180,417.4615385,18061.4359,134.3928417,3.106278082,62303.42163,1
17,4390,326,32257.33333,179.6032665,1.815111754,17219.19576,2
18,15514,227,5875.333333,76.65072298,2.961485439,30676.16867,3
19,17619,212,57981.42857,240.7933317,0.880423052,57932.1208,1

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` (or even base R) there should be a better way to write the `foo` function. However, since you haven't shared your data and you haven't shared what exactly is happening in `foo` we keep the `foo` function untouched and change the way in which we apply the function.

You can use `group_split` to split the data into different dataframes based on unique values in `subset` and `apply` `foo` to each dataframe using `map`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tmp2%>% 
  arrange(desc(mean_R),desc(sd_R)) %>%
  group_split(subset) %>% 
  map_df(foo) -> result

result
```

Comment: Hi Ronak! Thanks a lot for the help! I tried but I still get an error like below: ... is ignored in group_split(<grouped_df>), please use group_by(..., add = TRUE) %>% group_split()Error: 'tibbletmp2' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tibble' .         In the foo function , what I try to do is add a new column named"frontier dummy" and assign 0 or 1 for each row based on the criteria (whether it > A). Could you please help me figure out the error I got for the group split function? Thanks!

Comment: @JingyNiu Can you please provide data in a reproducible format for me to check why the error occurs? Edit your post with output of `dput(tmp2)` or `dput(head(tmp2, 20))` if your data is too big.

Comment: Thanks Ronak!! I did not figure out how to upload my data. I created an example data like above. Please let me know if it is not applicable.

Comment: I can suggest two changes. 1) In the `foo` function in `for` loop instead of `for (i in 2:nrow(tmp2)) {` use `for (i in seq_len(nrow(tmp2))) {`. 2) Start your code with ungrouping the dataframe. `tmp2%>% ungroup %>% arrange(desc(mean_R),desc(sd_R)).......`